# Disabling a link with jQuery while retaining script functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of clickable links where each `TR` is also clickable, going to the same link as in the `A` tag.

I've run into the issue where clicking on the `A` tag causes two windows to be opened, both going to the same link. If I disable the `A` tag, when I click on the link, the script on the `TR` doesn't run.

```
<table class="dataTable">
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class=" sorting_1">
            <strong>
                <a href="http://www.google.ca/" target="_blank">Form1</a>
            </strong> - [HTML]
            <br /><span class="contentSummary"> form 1 summary</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is it possible to have the script run when clicking on the disabled `A` tag?

```
$('.dataTable a').click(function() {
    return false;
});

$('.dataTable tbody tr').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    window.open(url);
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqscg/) example code here

Comment: Turns out the answer was to use

    `$('.dataTable a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });`

Instead of `return false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that your tr is clickable and handles the event i would style the text to look like a link.

remove the a tag all together

```
<span class="faux_link">Your Link Text</span>
```

Style this with text-decoration: underline and whatever link attributes you want

Then change up your tr a bit to include the link data you need

```
<tr data-link="yourdestination.html">
```

Then change up your javascript a bit

```
$('.dataTable tbody tr').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).data('link'); //this right here
    window.open(url);
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: This was the other option I was looking at. I chose the lazier approach, but this would strike me as the better option.